# How can I use variable in connection string?

Tags: c#, vb.net, .net-3.5

I'm having trouble with variables for connection strings. In my app.config database path seems fine but on form, I'm getting error for that connection string. When I try to add:

```
_connectionString = "Data Source = (LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB; " +
    "AttachDbFilename = \"|DataDirectory|\\gazi_db.mdf\"; " +
    "Integrated Security = True; Connect Timeout = 30";
```

the database won't work correctly; it can't save data on exit. However this Works fine:

```
connectionString = "Data Source = (LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB; " +
        "AttachDbFilename = \"C:\\Users\\Can\\Desktop\\c_sharp_gazi_installer" +
        "\\Gazi Installer\\gazi_installer\\gazi_db.mdf\"; " +
        "Integrated Security = True; Connect Timeout = 30";
```

How can I fix this?

**EDIT:** I hoped this would work

```
string DataDirectory = "";
string folder = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().CodeBase);
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", folder);

_connectionString = _connectionString = "Data Source = (LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB; " +
        "AttachDbFilename = \"" + DataDirectory + "\\gazi_db.mdf\"; " +
        "Integrated Security = True; Connect Timeout = 30";
```

But it's still giving me sqlclient sqlexception error.

**EDIT2:** This error indicates connection open. I don't understand why this doesn't work either:

```
SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
builder["Data Source"] = "(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB";
builder["AttachDbFilename"] = @"C:\Users\Can\\Desktop\c_sharp_gazi_installer\Gazi Installer\gazi_installer\gazi_db.mdf";
builder["Integrated Security"] = true;
builder["Connect Timeout"] = 30;
```

Please someone help. I'm going to go mad.

Comment: "I'm getting error". If only there was a way for us to know what the error message was.

Comment: If you create database from sqlserver management tool, instead of from VS, or attach the mdf file first, there will no longer be such problem.

Comment: oh that's what I was struggling with. I couldn't do that.

Comment: It gives me sqlexception error as I remember

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET has a [connection string builder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254947(v=vs.110).aspx) class. Using this you can set each value i.e. Data Source, Integrated Security separately to variables and then use the `.ConnectionString` property to get the connection string.

Comment: That isnt limited to c# - its a NET thing

Comment: Good call. Edited the original answer.

Comment: Thanks for all helps. Here's my final code: https://gist.github.com/nikel/1335c9573b1406cffc201d1c2e99746e

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you can use the @ "symbol" to avoid using so many escape characters.
Then, where did you define the "DataDirectory" variable?

Comment: I don't have it for now. I remember that I tried it as well. Just copied the string from app config.

Comment: shouldn't mdf placed in the same path with exe?

Comment: I tried this https://gist.github.com/anonymous/45f5fe567aefded419da2ccc98ebfec8 but am still getting sqlexception error.